# Data is not defined Jquery, PHP

Tags: php, jquery

I cant define data in ajax jquery function, where can be problem? I try everything, choose other server, other browser, remove cache, add data manually and always it is undefined...

Server: Laragon

App.js , add-new.php

```js
(function($){

    var form = $('#add-form');
    
    form.on('submit',function(){
        event.preventDefault();

        $.ajax({
            
            url: form.attr('action'),
            type: 'POST',
            data: form.serialize()
            
        })
        
        .done(function(data){
            console.log("Data: " + data);
        });
    });

}(jQuery))
```

```css
<?php 

die("test");
//include

require('./config.php');

$id = $database->insert('items',[
    'text' => $_POST['message']
]);

if($id){

    die('success');

}

?>
```

Response screen:

[response screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NCftq.png)

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Visit the [help], take the [tour] to see what and [ask]. If you get stuck, post a [mcve] of your attempt, noting input and expected output using the [`[<>]`](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/358992/ive-been-told-to-create-a-runnable-example-with-stack-snippets-how-do-i-do) snippet editor. Post CODE, not pictures of code

Comment: You will get more and better answers if you include your code rather than sending a screenshot

Comment: Also it is likely your server not returning data. Look in the console's network tab

Comment: SOLVED with comment //php_error\reportErrors();

Answer (score 0):

I think you have missed success parameter in ajax function.

```
$.ajax({
      url: form.attr('action'),
      type: 'POST',
      data: form.serialize(),
      success: function(data) {
        console.log("Data => ", data);
       }
    });
```

Hope it may work for you.